# How to make the factorial of a number using a loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3 and i would like to make code to find the factorial of a number using a for loop, can anyone help me?

this is the code i already have:

```
def factorial_list(n):
    if n== 1:
        return [1]
    else if n== 2:
        return [1, 1]
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            #what should i put in here

 the code should output:

factorial_list(12)  --> [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800, 39916800]
```

can someone take a look at it and find what i should add

BTW i already checked and this is not a copy of any other questions because they never asked for a loop

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output? For example, what should `factorial_list(3)` return?

Comment: `2! is not [1,1]`

Comment: This looks like a `"Here is a code - this is your task - complete it as homework"` to me - which would make your invest in time and coding very little ... what is your problem here? Why are you unable to solve it yourself?

Comment: 0! = 1    1! = 1 thats why its the second variable in the list

Comment: It is not _my_ homework - and although asking here will reap a solution with minimal effort on your part does not teach you anything at all - it only sets you up for big failure because you shirked your homework. Coding is about figuring stuff out yourself - not asking on SO.

Comment: @TheoBoston   0! == 1 - why is there no if-clause for 0 in your code then? 2! is still not equal to 1 but 2... yout got the if clause for 1!

Answer (score 0):

A possible implementation:

```
def factorial_list(n):
    ret = [1]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        ret.append(ret[-1] * i)
    return ret
```

```
>>> factorial_list(12)
[1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600]
```